# How to do Factory Reset

Tags: factory-reset, privacy

I know the topic has been covered here. But this is something different. I got a Tablet in my workplace to work with. It has a primary email Id for which I don't know the password. So to remove this, I clicked on remove account, but it says it can't be done. Only a factory reset has to be done to remove this Id. I tried adding an alternate gmail id, but still it considers the same Id for which I don't know the Password. So I tried to look out for factory data reset option in Sdcard and Device storage. But there is no such option there. I tried all over the net, but couldn't find anything useful.

Can someone help me on how to do a factory reset without the factory reset option?

NOTE: The Tablet looks like an ipad with same kind of button. I am not sure about the name of it, but my guess is "MID".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try these steps:

1. Turn your device off
2. Press both volume button and power button.
3. You should be accessing the boot loader by now.
4. Look for the option "Clear storage / Factory settings" using the volume button. Once found press the power button to confirm.

Comment: Hi, thanks.But doing the second step, it simply boots normal. Doesn't get to boot loader or anything.

Comment: Did you press both volume button and the power button? Don't let go till the boot loader appears.

Comment: um.. what do you refer by boot loader?

Comment: The screen which appears before your phone boots.

Comment: no. It just gets on with the booting. I have tried pressing the buttons, until it reaches the home screen. It didn't help..

Comment: That's odd. Those steps I provided are standard operation to get into boot loaders for any Android device.

Comment: In my tablet (Micromax Funbook a.k.a P300), it is option button and power button combination. So, try that as well.

Comment: Also, my Android phone (LG Optimus One a.k.a P500) has this option under Settings->Privacy->Factory data reset. Possibly check the settings menu for such feature as well.

Comment: It's called Recovery Mode, not bootloader. Also there's no standard way to access it; devices differ, some may not even have a key combination.

Answer (score 1):

You simply looked in the wrong place in the settings. Factory reset is located in the privacy options. As for the "hardware way" described in the other answer: the key combinations are device-specific. As you didn't mention the name of your device, guessing the correct combination is like playing in a lottery ;)

Comment: there is nothing else in the Privacy also. It contains only,location option and back up my settings option.

Comment: @Andro_Selva again the wrong menu. I didn't write "location and security", but **privacy**. Please check again :) Hint: The symbol used for that menu usually looks like a fence.

Comment: +1, Worked for me on a Samsung Galaxy Tab.

Answer (score 0):

Steps For How To Do Factory Reset Your Smartphone

1. Open your device’s Settings. The Settings app can have varying icons
   depending upon on your specific device, and may be also found within
   the App Tray or by pushing the phone’s dedicated menu button.
2. Find your Factory Reset option. Depending on your device, the “Factory data reset” feature may be located in one of two sections within the Settings app.

   Select the “Privacy” settings, and scroll down to “Factory reset
   Select the “Backup and reset” settings, and scroll down to “Factory reset”.
3. Tap “Reset device” to delete all data and restore your device’s factory settings. The accounts that you are signed into will be
   displayed on the screen. By default, all your phone’s internal
   storage will be wiped.
   If you want to erase all of the data on your phone’s SD card as well, check the box at the bottom of the screen.
4. Confirm the process by selecting “Erase everything". This will delete all data and restore back to your device’s factory settings.
   Your phone will be as if it just came out of the box.